# Built stuck at 0.0% while bundling index.ios.js

Tags: ios, react-native

I don't know exactly why but all my react-native projects cannot build anymore today and I'm stuck with a the Bundling of `index.ios.js` at 0.0%.

I tried a couple of things but all my projects got the same issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**NOTE**: This workaround is for macOS.

Found out that the culprit was `watchman 4.7.0`.
My issues started after having upgraded to watchman 4.7.0 using `brew`.

Looks like there's an issue in this new version of watchman:
[watchman issues 358](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/358).

At the end I solved my issue removing **the content** of the `/usr/local/var/run/watchman/` folder.

Comment: removing the content of /usr/local/var/run/watchman/ folder worked for me

Comment: I reinstalled watchman after uninstalling and removing the watchman folder and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: I am still stuck at this issue. Removing watchman does not help. I am building android app and tried with actual device as well as emulator. I am working on Windows 10 platform. Any help is welcome.

Comment: what is /usr/local/var/run/watchman/? is is a folder? if yes, where can I find it in Windows?

Comment: Sorry to not have made this clear, but this was done on macOS. I have never used ReactNative on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several things: the above answer, launchctl unload, restart, reinstall... You name it. Here's how I fixed it on MacOS:

TL;DR: Remove brew version and follow [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html) to compile from source. Use flags on configure: `--enable-statedir=$HOME/.watchman --without-python --without-pcre`

Reasoning: I don't need python bindings. I also suspect some permission issues and thought using my home would be safer than default path.

steps:

- `brew rm watchman`
- (just to be safe) `launchctl unload -F ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist`
- (just to be safe) restart mac
- `git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git`
- `cd watchman`
- `git checkout v4.9.0` // Prefer lastest version here.
- `brew install autoconf automake libtool` // Compilation tools
- `./autogen.sh`
- `./configure --enable-statedir="$HOME/.watchman" --without-python --without-pcre`
- `make` // Wait... It'll compile the .o files
- `make install` // If it fails try with `sudo` but it shouldn't.

After make install it should be in your path here: `/usr/local/bin/watchman`
Try to `watchman version` or something. Try to see if it fixed your problem.

Keep in mind most people have their stuff in `/usr/local/var/run/watchman/`. Our equivalent is now `~/.watchman/`

Let me know if this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

run the following command
**echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p**

Answer (score 0):

This also may happen in case your node dependencies are not installed, e.g. `node-modules/` in `.gitignore` and repo is freshly-pulled.

In this case, your should do `npm install` of `yarn` (in case you are using `yarn`).